# Search titles does not work with OSQA on Windows with MySQL - how to resolve?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, osqa

With OSQA installed using IIS and MySQL, tag search works, however questions search does not.  All results show blank.

I read through [this](http://meta.osqa.net/questions/84/why-search-does-not-search-in-question-body) post and [this one](http://meta.osqa.net/questions/10378/why-does-question-search-on-my-osqa-instance-not-work), but I don't see an actual solution.  If I missed it can someone please clarify or provide a solution?

I also found [this post](http://meta.osqa.net/questions/6132/mysql-full-text-search) which refers to [this link](http://svn.osqa.net/browse/OSQA/osqa/trunk/forum_modules/mysqlfulltext/fts_install.sql?r=HEAD) to download a MySQL module to enable FTS, however that link results in a server error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the contents of fts_install.sql (just do a search for that file) (below).  Had to make some small modifications to the `INSERT` statements, but seems to work:

```
ALTER TABLE osqa634.forum_mysqlftsindex CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER osqa634.fts_on_insert AFTER INSERT ON osqa634.forum_node
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO osqa634.forum_mysqlftsindex 
    SET node_id=NEW.id, 
        title=UPPER(NEW.title), 
        body=UPPER(NEW.body), 
        tagnames=UPPER(NEW.tagnames); 
  END;
|

delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER osqa634.fts_on_update AFTER UPDATE ON forum_node
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE osqa634.forum_mysqlftsindex 
    SET title = UPPER(NEW.title), 
    body = UPPER(NEW.body), 
    tagnames = UPPER(NEW.tagnames) 
    WHERE node_id = NEW.id;
  END;

|

INSERT INTO osqa634.forum_mysqlftsindex (node_id, title, body, tagnames) 
SELECT id, UPPER(title), UPPER(body), UPPER(tagnames) FROM osqa634.forum_node;
```

Seems to do the trick.